# Flask server: sending image file with ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, flask

What I have beeen trying to do is somehow send back an image object with an ajax request to my webpage. I have done a few options that I found on the internet but none were successful. If I am correct you can't send back objects via flask but I did not really find an alternative or how else to do it.

This is my ajax request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#left').bind('click', function() {
        var form = $('form#data')[0]; // 
        var formData = new FormData(form);

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url_for('encode') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#img-2").attr("src", data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        });
});
```

And this is my flask function that is called:

```
@app.route('/encode', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def encode():
    a = request.form['text']
    img = request.files['files']
    secret = lsb.hide(img, a)
    return secret
```

Is there any way I could send back the encoded image file and show it on the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to encode an image into base64 in order to display it in html.

So what you need is not sending back an object but sending back the encoded value. And then it is just a normal response.